# Regex, excluding a word

Tags: regex

```
egrep 'session\.[^0].*' i
```

will exclude

```
session.1.something 
session.2.something 
session.abc.something
session.def.something
```

How would you modify the regex to exclude not abc?

I would have thought that this would work, but it does not

```
egrep 'session\.^(abc).*' i
```

I'd like to get back

```
session.1.something 
session.2.something 
session.def.something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work fine

```
egrep 'session\.^(?!abc).*' i
```

Comment: Yup, just found that `egrep 'sessions\.[^(|abc)].*' i` works as well. Can you please explain what is the significance of `?!` or `|` in my example?

Comment: That's Lookahead and Lookbehind Assertions. See this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: With `|` you match multiple selection. Like `/(hi|bye|hello)/`