# how to Exclude specific word using regex?

Tags: regex

i have a problem here, i have the following string

`@Novriiiiii yauda busana muslim @nencor haha. wa'alaikumsalam noperi☺`

then i use this regex pattern to select all the string

`\w+`

however, i need to to select all the string except the word which prefixed with @ like `@Novriiiiii` or `@nencor` *which means, we have to exclude the @word ones*

how do i do that ?

ps. i am using regexpal to compile the regex. and i want to apply the regex pattern into yahoo pipes regex. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex, excluding a word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626405/regex-excluding-a-word)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookbehind so that if a word is preceded by `@` it is excluded.  You also need a word boundary before the word or else the lookbehind will only affect the first character.

```
(?<!@)\b\w+
```

http://rubular.com/r/ONEl70Am5Q

Comment: Note that this syntax is not common to all regex flavours; it works in Perl-style regexes but I'm not sure if it'll work in Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: @nencor regexpal uses JavaScript which does not have lookbehinds; I'm not sure if yahoo pipes does

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

http://rubular.com/r/uuXvNrUiGJ

```
[^@\w+]\w+
```

Comment: you almost got it, and it left some fullstop (.) i need the @word only

Answer (score 0):

This would sole your problem indeed:

```
[^@\w+][\w.]+
```

Check this link: http://regexr.com?34tq7

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a negative lookbehind as other answers have already suggested, here's a workaround.

`\w` already doesn't match the `@` character, so you'd want something like this:

```
[^@]\w+
```

But this will (a) not work at the beginning of the string, and (b) include the character before the word in the match. To fix (a), we can do:

```
(^|[^@])\w+
```

To fix (b), we parenthesize the part we want:

```
(^|[^@])(\w+)
```

Then use `$2` or `\2` (depending on regex dialect) to refer to the matched word.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to include the `@` symbol in the word:

```
[\w@]+
```

And then add another step in your Pipe to filter out all words that start with an `@`.

Comment: You should have edited your earlier answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: No. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: That link just has opinions of some users. Since you're solving a specific problem here its better to provide all your options in same answer (if for nothing it gives better readability to future visitors)

Comment: This way, good answers can be voted to the top independently of the bad ones, so it will _improve_ readability; otherwise, future visitors won't be able to tell which particular approach from the answer is considered better by the voters. You may disagree but it's accepted practice on SO.

Comment: I have seen this rarely, majority of posters edit their original answer and provide different options.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is to remove words that you don't want. Example:

```
find: @\w+
replace: empty string
```

you obtain the text without *@abcdef* words.